# Зафиксировать шапку

Tags: html, css

Есть [сайт](http://lp.website.com.kz/) На нем есть верхнее меню. При нажатии на один из пунктов меню идет плавный скролинг до нужного места. А как сделать так, чтобы шапка всегда была вверху? Ниже код шапки

```
<header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-line">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Filigrano"></a>
                </div>
                <nav class="main-mnu">
                    <ul class="clearfix">
                        <li><a href="#ex1">Каталог</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ex2">Получите подарок</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ex3">Отзывы</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ex4">Контакты</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <div class="phone">
                    <span><b>+7(824) 653-91-03</b></span>
                    <a class="btn" style="cursor: pointer;">Заказать звонок</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="h-text">
                    <h3>Победитель конкурса "Лучший ювелирный магазин" в номинации «Драгоценные сети» 2015 г.</h3>
                    <h1 class="title">Ювелирные украшения Filigrano</h1>
                    <h2>Подчеркните cвою индивидуальность</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="request">
                    Оставьте заявку прямо сейчас и получите новогодний подарок:
                    <span>дисконт в сети ювелирных салонов</span>
                    <span class="btn-yellow btn" style="color: #000000; font-size:22px; cursor: pointer;">Получить дисконт Filigrano</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: приблизительно так https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kuv459vc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько вещей.

1. Вам придется содержимое `<div class="header">` выдвинуть вне `<header>`
2. После этого добавить вот такой стиль:

> ```
> header {  
> background-color: white;  
> position: fixed;  
> top: 0;  
> z-index: 100;  
> width: 100%;  
> }
> ```

Думаю, что это Вам поможет.

Comment: Помогло спасибо

Comment: Спасибо большое. И мне помогло)